# Is there a way to fold text by indent but start that indent checking at a certain column?

Tags: logging, text-editor, code-folding

The platform I develop for spits out hundreds of thousands of lines of "stuff". The information it spits out is really quite good, with a timestamp, incidentID, trace level, and calling class on the left then some white space, then the actual log entry itself. We use AspectJ and some log4J stuff which results in various scopes being logged out. We'll get the method name and supplied parameters then indents to show all the logs from within that method call, then it will return. Every new scope is a new indent.

The problem I'd love to solve, either by finding a supported editor, or finding some example opensource project/code, is how to do texd folding based on this tabbed text but the tab inded must start so many characters past the first informational column.

Example of what my logs look like in a micro sense:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    xxxxxxxxxx
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      yyyyyyyy
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      yyyyyyyy
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    xxxxxxxxxx
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    zzzzzzzzzz
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      uuuuuuuu
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa        iiiiii
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa        iiiiii
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa      uuuuuuuu
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa    zzzzzzzzzz
```

I'd like to be able to fold out scope: iiiiiiii

Answer (score 0):

In [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor, it seems possible to make a custom lexer. Current lexer named "Text with indentation" (in add-ons) needs to be changed+ renamed. What to change: open lexer editor as shown in the CudaText wiki, find RegEx in lexer `(?<=^[\x20\x09]*).+` and change it to find block after "initial indent". You can change this regex to something like `(?<=^aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[\x20\x09]*).+` (not tested here).

Wiki: https://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Lexers_editing

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm not familiar with lexers or this particular editor so it may take a while to figure it all out.